# How to make Bootsfaces datatable display a dialog box on row selection

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

Currently working on a project which uses Bootsfaces. I have a bootsfaces datatable in which i need to open a dialog box upon row selection. Please advice how to proceed.

Below is the code

```
    <b:dataTable onclick="$('viewBKDDialog').show()" 
                                 update=":ViewBKDForm" 
                                 value="#{bookingAdminController.itemsBookDet}" 
                                 var="car" ajax="true" select="true" responsive="true"  >
</b:dataTable>
```

and i m using

```
<ui:include src="ViewBookingDetails_all.xhtml"/>
```

as the dialog box.

Comment: Please show what you already tried... Not that I'm able to help (no bootsfaces user) but it is required for others to

Comment: sorry..my mistake.update the code..let me know..if this would be sufficient...onclick is what is tried..i dont know to do this...

Comment: Can someone upvote the question? IMHO the question is good, it was probably downvoted for reasons that have been solved by the latest edit of @rahul. It would be a pity if the question was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I don't have the complete solution, but let's analyze your code. That's interesting enough.

First of all, you want to open a modal dialog based on the selected row. (Actually, the "modal dialog" bit is an educated guess). However, you added the `onclick` handler to the entire table. JSF doesn't make the rows explicit, so you have to add the `onclick` handler to the cells of the table. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume you've assigned the `onclick` handler to a button within the table.

Second, there's a bug in every BootsFaces version <= 0.9.1 that prevents you from detecting which row has been selected. So you have to use a version >= 0.9.2. At the time of writing, that's the developer snapshot BootsFaces-0.9.2-SNAPSHOT. See [issue 369 on how to get it](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/369) and [issue 486 on the row-select bug](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/486) I've recently solved.

Third, you should take in mind that the JavaScript code of the `onclick` handler is executed before the AJAX request. I can only guess, but I assume that you want to update the content of the modal dialog based on the row selection. I also assume that the content is defined by an AJAX request. If both assumptions are true, you've got a problem. The `onclick` handler is executed before the AJAX call. So I suggest you use the `oncomplete` JavaScript callback handler that's offered by some BootsFaces components, such as `b:commandButton`.

Like I've said before, that's not a complete solution, but I hope it helps nonetheless.

Comment: I understand that onclick is javascript handler and will be called after ajax request. Let me try oncomplete and update bootsfaces verssion. Will get back to you with results today. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Not after. The `onclick` handler is executed before the `f:ajax` request is triggered. You have slightly more control when you use the BootsFaces way: `onclick="console.log("before AJAX");ajax:myBean.doSomething();javascript:console.log("after AJAX")`. In the case the the second log statement is shown after sending the AJAX request. However, the AJAX request is asynchronous, so it will almost always be processed after the second log statement.